# HTML form onSubmit attribute issue with location.href

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a form whose opening tag looks like this

```
<form name="adv_search_form" action="" onSubmit="location.href = location.href.split('#')[0]+'&adv_search=adv_search'" method="POST">
```

actually, the value of `location.href` is `http://localhost/projectcode12may2014/ampanel/index.php?rel=common_listing&module=company#`

I want to append a `&adv_search=adv_search` to the url when the form is submitted, that too after removing the `#` from the url to make it `$_GET`able.
So when I do

```
<form name="adv_search_form" action="" onSubmit="location.href = location.href+'&adv_search=adv_search'" method="POST">
```

things work pretty well but the hash persists in the url. So I had used the form opening tag as the former one. But when I do so, nothing happens and the url doesn't change at all. Can anyone help me out on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the substring-method to eliminate the '#' at the end:

```
location.href = location.href.substring( 0, location.href.length-1 ) +
                '&adv_search=adv_search';
```

Comment: This is not working. Please refer to the question again, nothing apart from `location.href = location.href+'&adv_search=adv_search'` is changing the URL

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you handle with PHP the correct onSubmit URL and don't rely on the client location.href for that. Can result in unwanted behavior.

If you really want it then you can use str.replace() for this.

```
original = location.href+'&adv_search=adv_search';
original.str_replace('#', '');
```

Comment: This is not working. Please refer to the question again, nothing apart from `location.href = location.href+'&adv_search=adv_search'` is changing the URL

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution of my problem. The url was changing but it was being overwritten by the `action` when the form gets submitted. I had to deprecate the default behavior of the form by adding `return false` in the onSubmit attribute. 
Anyways, Thanks for your answers.